# Inject Array of Interfaces using NMock C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I am new to NUnit and have question regarding how to inject array of Interface objects in Constructor of the test object. For ex:

```
Class Class1 
{
   private ITest[] iTests;
   private ITest1 iTest1;

   Class1(ITest1 iTest1, ITest[] iTests)
   {
      this.iTests = iTests;
      this.iTest1 = iTest1;
   }
}

[TestFixture()]
class Class1UnitTest
{
    private Mock<ITest1> iTest1;
    private Class1 class1;

    [SetUp]
    public void setUp ()
    {
      this.iTest1 = new Mock<ITest1>();
      class1 = new Class1 (this.iTest1.Objeсt, ????);
    }
}
```

Can someone please let me know how to inject ITest[] in the unit test?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I do not see your array, I just see `this.iTest1.Object` that is `ITest1` not `ITest[]`. What do you want to pass into constructor as array? Can you give some example?

Comment: Oops sorry for the mistake. I edited my intent in the question. I want to know how to inject `ITest[] ` as evident now. Let me know if it is not clear still

Comment: @VenuChitta Just create an array and populate it with mocks just like the one you created before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array and populate it with mocks just like the one you created before.

```
[TestFixture()]
class Class1UnitTest {
    private Mock<ITest1> iTest1;
    private ITest[] iTests;
    private Class1 class1;

    [SetUp]
    public void setUp () {
      this.iTest1 = new Mock<ITest1>();

      var mock1 = new Mock<ITest>();
      var mock2 = new Mock<ITest>();
      var mock3 = new Mock<ITest>();

      this.iTests = new ITest[] {
          mock1.Object,
          mock2.Object,
          mock3.Object,
          //...
      }
      class1 = new Class1 (this.iTest1.Objeсt, this.iTests);
    }
}
```

You could even create a helper method to DRY the code

```
public T[] MockArray<T>(int length) where T : class {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, length).Select(i => new Mock<T>().Object).ToArray();
}
```

And call it in the test

```
this.iTests = MockArray<ITest>(5);
```